# Android studio keeps showing red line on flutter code

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Just this week i noticed my android studio keeps showing red line underneath my flutter code

[image]

[My Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBHr0.png)

Comment: Can you share a screensot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbI8X.png

Comment: please share your logcat

Comment: or try to restart adb server `killall -9 adb sudo ./adb` and  `start-server` . because device is not found in image

Comment: What is the error it's showing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the installation location of Flutter recently try removing .packages file in your project directory and run `flutter pub get` again.

Comment: Can you post your `flutter doctor` output?